# zerorpc: how to convert string data from python to node

Tags: python, node.js, string, binary, zerorpc

I need to call a python script from [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) and getting back the result. I found the [zerorpc](http://www.zerorpc.io) library which seems a good fit. The python script returns an array of strings but in node i got objects of binary data.

This is the python zerorpc server:

```
# python zerorpc server

import zerorpc

class HelloRPC(object):

    def test(self):
        return ["A", "B", "C"]

server = zerorpc.Server(HelloRPC())
serrver.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:4242")
server.run()
```

This is the node zerorpc client:

```
// nodejs zerorpc client

var zerorpc = require("zerorpc")    

var client = new zerorpc.Client();
client.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4242");

client.invoke("test", function(error, response, more) {
    if (response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            console.log(typeof response[i], response[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives this output:

```
object <Buffer 41>
object <Buffer 42>
object <Buffer 43>
```

Which is the best way to convert these objects in strings in nodejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node JS Buffer class has the toString method

```
strings[i] = response[i].toString("utf8")
```

See the method:
https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end